# Client Script for Now Mobile or Agent Mobile servicenow

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api, servicenow-client-scripts, servicenow-hrsd

I have configured a input form screen for creating a new record.

I have a use case as follows:

```
         I want to auto populate the fields based on the value updated in other fields.
```

Is there any way to achieve this in now mobile or agent mobile.

please provide me with the solution.

It will really be helpful

I am figuring out a way to achive this I am not able to find any suitable approach to follow